# How to animate views according to tableview scrolling directions without content scrolling

Tags: ios, header, popup, tableview, shrink

i'm trying to implement a specific tableview behaviour (Like on Facebook app).

I want to have a dynamic header that will be magnified every time the user scrolls up and will be shrieked when the user scroll down.

In addition i want the tableview to cause the effect of pushing the header and than scrolling the tableview cells.

I used the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
```

in this method i calculated the offset and the direction and called a method that shrink or magnify the header accordingly

so far so good.

The thing is that the animation is being performed with the tableview scrolling.

To avoid it, I created a custom scrollview on to of the top of my tableview, I taged the two scrollviews differently.

In the scrollview i created a weak reference of the tableview and a boolean value that indicated if the scrollview should return the tableview touch.

When the shrinking\magnifying  animation was finished i changed the boolean value so it will signal the custom scrollview to return the tableview in my HitTest methods that i implemented inside the scrollview.

But hitTest not called when the user keep scrolling (without leafing the finger), in additions now my buttons inside my tableViewCell aren't reacting.

Here is my HitTest Method:

```
 - (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

```
 UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
if (_recieveTouchOnTable)
{

    return _table;

}
else
return result;
```

}

Here is my scrollViewDidScroll method: 
(onProgress means that the animation is being performed, so keep returning the custom scrollview)
Tag = 2 = the custom scrollview
Tag = 1 = the tableview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

 CGFloat yVelocity = [aScrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:aScrollView].y;

CGFloat offset = lastCustomScrollViewContentOffset.y-aScrollView.contentOffset.y;

lastCustomScrollViewContentOffset =aScrollView.contentOffset;

if (yVelocity<0)
    offset = fabs(offset)*-1;

else if(yVelocity>0)
    offset = fabs(offset);

if (offset!=0 && aScrollView.tag == 2)
[self layoutViewAccorrdingToTableviewScorlingVelocity:offset];

if (!onProgress ){
      customScrollView.recieveTouchOnTable=YES;  
}
```

}

Am i missing something, or maybe there's a more simple way to do it?